# need assistance for mojavi framework?

Tags: symfony

I am working on a framework named mojavi I can't find any tutorial regarding the framework I am in a  desperate situation I can't find any tags regarding the framework so I am posting it in symfony as it uses helper function from symfony

Comment: Development for mojavi stopped in 2008.  Are you trying to support a legacy application?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/mojavitutorial.html

Note: this tutorial applies to Mojavi version 2 (PHP4). It's no longer up-to-date, but I leave it here in case anyone finds it of use. See the Mojavi site for more recent info, and if you want a complete application framework, I'd recommend Symfony, which is based on Mojavi and is now used to power this site.